# ANT4Eclipse package-info is already defined

Tags: eclipse, ant4eclipse

```
< project name="ant-in-eclipse" basedir="."  xmlns:ant4eclipse="antlib:org.ant4eclipse" xmlns:antcontrib="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" default="compileAndJar">
  < import file="a4e-jdt-macros.xml"/>
  < ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary
       name="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v70/was.base.v7">
      <fileset dir="../IBMLib">
        <include name="lib/**/*.jar"/>
        <include name="plugins/**/*.jar"/>
        <include name="feature_packs/jpa/plugins/**/*.jar"/>
        <exclude name="feature_packs/jpa/plugins/**/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jpa.jar"/>
      </fileset>
  </ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary>
  < ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary
       name="com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxrs.internal.project.facet.v7.jaxrslibrarycontainer">
      <fileset dir="../IBMLib">
        <include name="web2fep/**/*.jar"/>
        <include name="web2fep/optionalLibraries/jaxrs/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
  </ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary>

  <target name="compileAndJar">
    <buildJdtProject workspacedirectory="." projectname="wfn-ws-client">
      <finish>
        <jar destfile="deploy/wfn-ws-client.jar">
          <ant4eclipse:jdtProjectFileSet workspacedirectory="."
              projectname="${buildJdtProject.project.name}"/>
        </jar>
      </finish>
    </buildJdtProject>
  </target>
</project>
```

I am getting an error called

```
[javac] 46. ERROR in /data/temp/ANT/PSFBUILD/wfn-ws-client/src/com/adp/wfn/reporting/myreport/package-info.java (at line 1)
[javac] //
[javac] ^
[javac] The type package-info is already defined
[javac] ----------
```

Can any one please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a **[bug report that has been filed for this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322789).** Perhaps this is of help for you. You might also try to trigger another build through ant, or perhaps look into the nesting of your directories.